# Well as an adverb modifying an adjective

Tags: british-english, intensifying-adverbs

I notice that there has been a change in the word *well*. Examples are:

- She's well nice.
- It's well good.

Is this a West of England term (I lived there for a while), or has it just entered the language?

Comment: A modifier to an adjective (like *nice*) is generally an adverb. See [Oxford sense 2.3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/well).

Comment: David, I've edited your post to correct the title as per @AndrewLeach's comment; this should encourage a more positive reception (since this site is for "serious language enthusiasts", misclassifying a part of speech would not be welcomed!). If this is not what you want to ask, you can "roll back" the edit to the original.

Comment: To my (American English) ear, those do sound unusual in a "probably British dialect of some sort" way. But on the other hand, there's the set phrase *well pleased* which sounds perfectly natural to me, especially in the negative (*they were not well pleased*).

Comment: "I notice ..." -- try and provide the sources for reference.

Answer (score 5):

OED lists this sense of *well* (as an adverbial intensifier) as sense IV:

> **IV.** As an intensifier with adjectives, numerals, adverbs, etc.
>    **16.** With adjectives.
>    **a.** In general use, in a variety of constructions, typically without complement, in senses varying from ‘fully, completely’ to ‘fairly, considerably, rather’.

They include a citation from 1962 (my emphasis):

> 1962   S. Ennis tr. P. Sayers *Old Woman's Refl.* vi. 32   **It was well late** when I reached Flagstone a little below Vicarstown, and those little things delayed me.

However the earliest citations don't have a date, coming from Old English (Early Old English was used 400–700 AD):

> eOE   tr. Bede *Eccl. Hist.* (Tanner) iv. ii. 258   Wæron her stronge cyningas & wel cristne [L. fortissimos Christianosque habentes reges].
>   eOE   *Bald's Leechbk.* (Royal) (1865) ii. ii. 180   Pisan ofþænda & gesodena on ecede & on wætre & on wine wel scearpum.
>   OE   *Blickling Homilies* 217   Þa wæs he þær dagas wel manige.
>   lOE   King Ælfred tr. Boethius *De Consol. Philos.* (Bodl.) (2009) I. xxv. 293   Seo leo, þeah hio wel tam se.., gif hit æfre gebyreð þæt heo blodes onbirigð, heo forgit sona hire niwan taman.

So no, it's not recent nor a West Country use.

*<sub>[I would generally translate texts which are not really recognisable English, but in this case my Old English is not up to the task.]</sub>*

Comment: it's primarily London ("Cockney") dialectical. Also common in South East England ("Estuary") dialect. For some years a BBC "EastEnders" soap character had a dog called "Well 'Ard" (Well Hard).

Comment: I tend to think this is OED sense 16c not its 16a. And the bracketed Latin from Bede is easier for me than the Old English! “Being very strong and Christian kings”. The “well Christian” bit is in the OE only, not the Latin, although the Latin does have very strong modifying Christian. But I believe that *waeron* was a finite *be* verb in the preterite plural, so like *were* today, but the bracketed Latin is not a finite verb at all. This, it’s all close enough.

Comment: Is this "OED" publicly accessible? If so, would not the Q be GR?

Comment: @Kris OED is not publicly accessible, which is why I haven't linked to it.

Comment: There ought to be some publicly accessible online resource that deals with this helpfully enough?

Comment: @kris It's called ELU.SE. OED is available to anyone in the UK with a public library subscription, but it's difficult to get at from abroad.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an adjectival use of *well*. Adjectival uses include such things as these:

- I am not a well man. (*attributive use*)
- I don’t feel well. (*predicative use*)
- He’s not well. (*predicative use*)

The sort of use you mention here isn’t really even an adverb, either, at least in modern analysis. Rather, it is an ***intensifier***, much like *very*. In older analyses, intensifiers were usually classified as adverbs. However, they can only modify other modifiers, not verbs, which makes them something of an odd sort of adverb. (Then again, there are scads of odd sorts of adverbs.)

The OED covers this in that word’s section IV for intensifier use, and specifically under sense 16c, where it calls it “British slang”.

> IV. As an intensifier with adjectives, numerals, adverbs, etc.
>
> 16. With adjectives.
>
>     a. In general use, in a variety of constructions, typically without complement, in senses varying from ‘fully, completely’ to ‘fairly, considerably, rather’.
>
>     > Formerly in common use; now chiefly with *asleep, awake, open*, and as implied in sense A. 16b.
>
>     With predicative adjectives (chiefly *able, aware, capable, familiar, suitable, willing*, and *worth*) complemented by an infinitive, *that*-clause, noun phrase, or prepositional phrase: to a substantial extent, more than somewhat; certainly, undoubtedly, thoroughly. See also **well worthy** *adj*.
>
>     > In *well worthwhile* the noun complement while is now treated as the second element of a compound adjective.
>
>     c. ***Brit. slang***. Used as an intensifier to qualify (chiefly predicative) adjectives, with emphatic force: downright, absolutely. Cf. *good and* at **good** *adj*. 12c.
>
>     > In this use sentence stress usually falls on *well* rather than the following adjective.

As to whether this has just entered the language, the OED’s earliest citation is from only 1972, so it appears that your suspicion may be correct.

> - 1972   J. Speight *Till Death us do Part: Scripts* (1973) 133  
>    *Rita*: God's got the churches. 
>   *Mike*: Yeah, the way property is gazumping, He's got to be well loaded.

With the most recent citation being:

> - 2012   *Independent* 7 Sept. 15/3 
>     Louboutin is well chuffed and says that everybody knows a red sole is a Louboutin sole and now it’s enshrined in law.

There’s also a citation from *Eastenders*:

> - 1998   A. Wood *EastEnders* (BBC TV script) (O.E.D. Archive) Episode 642. 61  
>     *Mick*. If Lola doesn't make it we’ll just have to play background music. 
>    *Lenny*. That’ll look well naff won't it?

However, that’s just for 16c; there are many earlier citations for 16a and 16b dating back to Old English.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using the online OED? I would say this is simply *very*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, that’s the Online OED, from [here](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/226983). It’s been updated since the OED2 that many of us have copies of, in December of 2014 if I read the history right.